# creating a list from two ints

Tags: c#

I have some code that looks like this:

```
int A = 3;
int B = 5;
List<int> TheList = new List<int>();

TheList.Add(A);
TheList.Add(B);

SomeFunction(TheList);
```

Is there some way to write something like this:

```
SomeFunction((A,B).ToList());
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes:

```
new List<int>{A, B}
```

produces a list with the two elements that you specified. You can pass that list to a function or do anything else with it.

Note that if your target function takes `IList<int>` rather than a `List<int>`, you could shorten the syntax some more by sending a new array of `int`s, because arrays `T[]` implement their corresponding `IList<T>` interface.

Comment: Can I put that in the parameters of the function call?

Comment: @frenchie Absolutely, you can.

Answer (score 2):

```
SomeFunction(new List<int> { A, B });
```